# Plotting a gene in Seurat

Tags: r, rna-seq, scrnaseq, seurat, visualization

I saw in the extensive Seurat documentation for Dimplot (dimensional reduction plot), [here](https://satijalab.org/seurat/reference/dimplot), you can plot a gene by specifying it with group.by = "gene" but this does not work in practice.

```
> p <- DimPlot(DG.combined, reduction = "umap", group.by = "Fos")
Error: Cannot find 'Fos' in this Seurat object
> p <- DimPlot(DG.combined, reduction = "umap", group.by = "Inhba")
Error: Cannot find 'Inhba' in this Seurat object
```

Am I mistaken?  Do I need to add a metadata column containing expression of the gene?  How can I access individual cells gene expression data in seurat so I can create a metadata label based on binned expression levels?  Also how would I tell seurat to use a color gradient to label them?

References
https://satijalab.org/seurat/reference/dimplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @swbarnes2 has suggested, you can plot gene expression over the top of a dimensional reduction using the `FeaturePlot` function, using the `features` parameter for gene names:

```
p <- FeaturePlot(DG.combined, reduction = "umap", features = c("Fos", "Inhba"))
```

See the 3k tutorial here:

https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial.html#cb49

Answer (score 2):

I am not totally sure what you are trying to do, but I think you want FeaturePlot, not DimPlot